# Is there a way to see what data stores each app in phone memory/on sd card?

Tags: android

I want to track everything that apps store in phone memory/on sd card, so I can delete it if the app is uninstalled. Is this possible? If not, how can I get all the files from phone memory/sd card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to "track" what your application creates, i think..
generally, the app stores data in the Cache directory, which is :

```
 "<storage directory>/data/<your package name>/"
```

on a device which supports external storage, the "storage directory" is generally "/mnt/sdcard"

you can read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to learn how to use the External storage to save files you create through your application.

I'd also like to point out that there is no way for you to know when your app is being uninstalled, so you can't delete the files before uninstall manually anyway,if that's what you intend to do. The android system itself removes the files stored in your cache directory, though.

Comment: I know about "<storage directory>/data/<your package name>/" but that's not I want. I think it is deleted by android when the app is uninstalled anyway. What I actually want to do is track what other apps create, and let the user delete that data after an app is uninstalled. Not just me, but many android users tend to install then uninstall many apps. Some of them leave behind folders and files which I don't need. I think this would be a very practical app.

Comment: Yes, it would be. But there is no way to do that, yet. Maybe, in the future.